# How to connect Unity with android native lib?

Tags: android, c++, unity-game-engine

I have a native (c++) android lib that I build in Android studio and this lib has an extension `.arr`. I need to use this lib in Unity as android plugin. So, I would like to clarify what is the correct way to connect this lib with Unity.

As far as I understand it should be like this:

1. Create c# script
2. Create Unity native plugin (actually it Visual Studio dll lib project)
3. Connect this native plugin with my native lib that I build in Android Studio

If I miss something here?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You be more specific according to the [Unity Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AndroidAARPlugins.html)

> To add an AAR plug-in to your Project, copy the .aar file anywhere within the Assets/Plugins/Android/libs path, then select it in Unity to open the Import Settings in the Inspector
> window. Enable the Android checkbox to mark this .aar file as compatible with Unity

So Provided your `.arr` is ready at hand it should be easy peasy